# MOSFET driven LED AVR blinker circuit exibits flakey behavior

Tags: avr, mosfet

The following circuit, built on a prototypeboard/stripboard, sometimes fails to operate: it is dead to the world. No output regardless of the input. I originally thought that some of the soldered connections were flakey (on the basis of the fact that touching the the board would seem to cause the circuit to go dead or back alive), however, after checking the prototype board again, I couldn't find much of anything out of the ordinary, other than the resistance between Vcc and Gnd being 7.?? mega ohms.  I am wondering now if there is some mistake in the circuit design/logic?

[image]

The input is either 0V or 12V, and is connected to the uC via optocoupler. The uC listens for the input, and flashes the various leds while the input is 12V and turns them off when input goes back to 0V. Full code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

volatile uint8_t  useless = 0;

ISR(INT0_vect) {     
  useless ^= 0xFF;
}


int main(void) {

// Using PCINT0 as low-level interrupt

MCUCR &= ~ ( (1<<ISC01)|(1<<ISC00) );   // low level interrupt on INT0
GIMSK = 1 << INT0;                       // enable INT0 interrupt

#define OUTPUTA 4
#define OUTPUTB 3
#define INPUT   1
DDRB= 0x00|(1<<OUTPUTA)|(1<<OUTPUTB);
PORTB=0;

sei();    // enable interrupts

_NOP();

while (1) {
  if ( (PINB && (1<<INPUT)) == 0 ) {
    PORTB |= (1<<OUTPUTA)|(1<<OUTPUTB);
    while ( (PINB & (1<<INPUT)) == 0) {
      _delay_ms(170);
      PORTB^= (1<<OUTPUTA);
    }
    PORTB &= ~ ( (1<<OUTPUTA)|(1<<OUTPUTB) );
 }

 if (1) {
   // Go to sleep
   MCUCR |= 1<<SE;
   MCUCR = MCUCR && ~( (1<<SM1)|(1<<SM1) ) |  (1<<SM1)|(0<<SM1);
   sleep_cpu();

   // Wake up here
   MCUCR &= ~(1<<SE);
 }
```

My current best idea is to replce the 74HC14N (my apologies the Schmitt trigger is that, and not 74LS14), and the size of the smaller bypass cap (the circuit is powered by a 2-3A wallwart and there is quite a few LEDs)

**EDIT:** Fixed schematic vis-a-vis optocoupler output (thanks [Peter Benett](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/19835/peter-bennett))

**EDIT2** Fixed schematic to show that reset pin is tied to Vcc (thanks [geometrikal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/6481/geometrikal))

Comment: Have you made sure all your GNDs are connected together? The symptoms sound like a floating ground.

Comment: I think so. I'll double check that. Thanks.  But it isn't the case that _while_ you are touching it the circuit works, touching and letting go makes it work, until you touch it again, or the moon of Jupiter start rising in the Saggitarius

Comment: Something is floating.. RESET pin? Somehow pull ups got disabled?

Comment: Grrr.. another schematic error. Reset is actually tied to Vcc.

Comment: Try putting a 1uF capacitor from reset to ground. Try also shorting the reset pin to ground when it powers up flaky.

Comment: I may well be missing the main point (it happens) , but a quick flick through seems to indicate that PCINT0 (pin 5) is being enabled but not used except presumably to desleep the cpu. Does it even have a source? As you have a 170 mS delay what is the IRQ doing and what is the IRQ rate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a confusion between the bitwise AND operator `&` and the logic AND operator `&&`

For example this line in your code

```
if ( (PINB && (1<<INPUT)) == 0 )
```

doesn't become true only when bit1 of portB becomes high but when any of the bits is high. That happens because `(1<<INPUT)` is >0 so is always true and that leaves the check on PINB, it will be true with 0x01 or 0x02 or 0x03... 0xff

The correct way to check the state of PB1 is

```
if ( (PINB & (1<<INPUT)) == 0 )
```

Another place you use the wrong operator is

```
MCUCR = MCUCR && ~( (1<<SM1)|(1<<SM1) ) |  (1<<SM1)|(0<<SM1);
```

That results to either 0 or 1, what you should use is

```
MCUCR = MCUCR & ~( (1<<SM1)|(1<<SM1) ) |  (1<<SM1)|(0<<SM1);
```

---

Coming to your actual circuit, what is the need for 74LS14?
All you need is to enable the internal pull-up for PB1 and connect the opto transistor collector to the port pin to pull it down when active.

You can just wire it like

[image]

And as for the code, something like

```
// change the following clock frequency depending on the clock you use
#define F_CPU 9600000UL // 9.6 MHz`
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
//#include <avr/cpufunc.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

#define OUTPUTA 4
#define OUTPUTB 3
#define INPUT   1

volatile uint8_t  useless = 0;
volatile uint8_t  flashing_enable = 0;

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    if((PINB & (1 << INPUT)) == 0)
    {
        flashing_enable = 1; // set flashing flag
        PORTB |= (1 << OUTPUTA) | (1 << OUTPUTB); // turn on both leds
    }
    else
    {
        flashing_enable = 0; // clear flashing flag
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0x00 | (1 << OUTPUTA) | (1 << OUTPUTB);
    PORTB = (1 << INPUT); // enable pullup
    // External Interrupt(s) initialization
    // INT0: On
    // INT0 Mode: Any change
    // Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT0-5: Off
    GIMSK = (1 << INT0) | (0 << PCIE);
    MCUCR = (0 << ISC01) | (1 << ISC00);
    GIFR = (1 << INTF0) | (0 << PCIF);
    GIFR = (0 << INTF0) | (1 << PCIF);
    sei();    // enable interrupts

    while(1)
    {
        if(flashing_enable)
        {
            _delay_ms(170);
            PORTB ^= (1 << OUTPUTA);
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~((1 << OUTPUTA) | (1 << OUTPUTB));
        }
    }
}
```

I have used single leds just to show the generic connection scheme. I have also omitted the capacitors, add them in your actual hardware.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to check whether the code I posted is the code that's uploaded onto the ATtiny - I thought I got rid of those &/&& errors. But if this was indeed the root cause of the problem, I am not sure how it would result in flakey behavior rather than just never working. Any ideas? The Schmitt trigger provides hysteresis and inversion of the optocoupler output signal, which is necessary if low level interrupt is used on the ATtiny

Comment: @angelatlarge Using a low level interrupt level as opposed to edge trigger (like I did in my code) would be a cause of problems since it would call the interrupt handler repeatedly, not letting the mcu execute the rest of the code.

Comment: According to the datasheet "When the INT0 interrupt is enabled and is configured as level triggered, the interrupt will trigger as long as the pin is held low." but I am not sure that this should "let the mcu execute the rest of the code": the interrupt handler doesn't do much: in my tests, the rest of the code was indeed executed, when behavior was non-flakey (on the breadboard).

Comment: @angelatlarge I think that using the interrupt with level trigger can cause trouble and I would avoid it. I have no idea why and when your code executed since the input level wasn't read properly (at least from the && I saw).

Comment: Any reason to write to GIFR twice?

Comment: @angelatlarge No, there is no need to do it separately. I was going back and forth between the external interrupt and pin change interrupt and I was clearing only one of the flags each time (just the relevant one)  and I left both lines by mistake. Only the first line is needed, the second one can be omitted or merged with the first line (if you want to clear both flags).

Answer (score 0):

The input to the 74LS14 (pin 1) is tied to +5 volts, so any input via the optocoupler will have no effect.

I'd move R2 to connect between +5V and the 74LS14 pin 1, with pin 1 also connected to the opto collector, and the opto emitter grounded.  That will allow the opto to control the input to the 74LS14.

Comment: Sorry, got careless with the schematic while redrawing to save space. All fixed now.  If it was indeed wired as drawn previousely, it would never work. Currently it works intermittently.  Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues mentioned in the above answer, this line:

```
MCUCR &= ~ ( (1<<ISC01)|(1<<ISC00) );   // low level interrupt on INT0
```

Is also quite incorrect: not sure why I decided to invert the value loaded into `MCUCR`

After the adding a cap on the reset line (Thank you [@Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97122/mosfet-driven-led-avr-blinker-circuit-exibits-flakey-behavior/98634#comment189635_97122)), fixing the coding errors and switching to a low-going interrupt from low-level interrupt (both pointed out by [alexan_e](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/97145/19941)), the blinker seems fine. I kept the sleep function.